# Failed docker build has no logs - "configured logging driver does not support reading"

Tags: docker, logging, digital-ocean

I'm trying to debug a docker build on a Digital Ocean droplet but I can't seem to access any logs.

When I run the build command it returns an exit code 137. This is my build command:

```
docker build --build-arg env=staging -t name:tag .
```

I know this is has to do with being out of memory, but instead of just increasing RAM on the droplet I'd like to see if I can optimize the image. ([Sort of following this guide](https://bobcares.com/blog/error-137-docker/))

I can find the exited container by running `docker ps -a` but when I try to access the logs by running `docker logs <CONTAINTER_ID>` I get the following error:

`Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading`

So I tried to [configure the logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-default-logging-driver) by adding a `daemon.json` file to `/etc/docker` with the following code:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file"
}
```

When I check run `docker info --format '{{.LoggingDriver}}'` I get back `json-file` - so as far as I can tell that is the current default logging driver.

But when I try to build the image again (it doesn't work, 137 error as expected), I still get the same error when I try to access the logs:

`Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading`

When I try to inspect the logging driver the container is using by running: `docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' 3016507bd1dc` I get `none` back.

Does anyone what I'm missing or how I can get the logs of the failed build?

--- dockerfile ---

Node app with an Angular client

```
FROM node:11.14

ARG env
ENV NODE_ENV $env

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
COPY ./client/ ./client/

RUN npm install

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/client
RUN npm install && \
    npm install --only=dev && \
    npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe && \
    npm rebuild node-sass && \
    ng build --configuration=$env
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3040
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

--- jenkinsfile ---

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('clean') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker system prune -a -f || true'
      }
    }
    stage('build staging') {
      when {
        branch 'dev'
      }
      steps {
        sh '''docker build --build-arg env=staging -t NAME:stage .
  docker stop NAME-stage-c && docker rm NAME-stage-c || true
  docker run -d -p 3041:3040 --name NAME-stage-c NAME:stage
  '''
      }
    }
    stage('cleanup') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker system prune -a -f || true'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably Docker goes in OOM even before being able to assigned the logging driver. In any case looking at the logs is not a way to debug a build. Docker prints messages as it goes through the build process and that's what you should use.
Most importantly, you should not build on a droplet. You should build locally, push to a registry and use the droplet only to run the container. 
You can however post your Dockerfile and I can tell you if it can still be optimized.

Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mihai. That does make sense. To provide a bit more information; I'm using jenkins for CI whenever I push to github. I've got jenkins executing the build and then running the container. To your point about not building on a droplet, how can I avoid that while using jenkins?

Comment: You can have Jenkins on a special build droplet with more memory dedicated to only this task, or just have Jenkins on a different machine. You can even start Jenkins in docker on your own machine and run it there

Comment: Hmm, so I create a new droplet just for jenkins and my steps might look like: 
1) build the image on that droplet. 
2) push it to a registry. 
3) from the jenkins droplet somehow command the other droplet to pull from the registry and run the new container?

(I added my current jenkinsfile and dockerfile for reference to the original post)

Comment: Just to get this to work for now, I ended up adding swap space. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04